# different sets of notification icons based on notification bar color

Tags: android, user-interface, notifications

I am displaying a notification icon which is dark gray. It looks fine on Nexus One, where the notification area is light gray and is almost invisible on HTC Desire (Sense UI - dark gray notification bar). Is there a way to overcome that? (The icon cannot be changed).

Thanks a lot

EDIT: "The icon cannot be changed meaning" that I am using a custom set of icons which is a **must** for me.

Comment: "The icon cannot be changed" -- yes, it can. Please follow the design guidelines: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#statusbarstructure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest an outline of a different color. For example [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20091009202043/http://interfacelift.com/icons-win/previews/00994_outline.jpg).

If that doesn't work, how about a background like [this](https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-ui-color-shapes/128/thumbs-up-circle-blue-512.png) or [this](https://cdn.create.vista.com/api/media/small/247594690/stock-vector-thumbs-up-flat-white-icons-in-square-backgrounds)?

I hope this helps.

Yours,
Emmanuel

Comment: yes, that's what I did - an outline of a different color. thanks

Comment: None of the links are working